# How to determine if threads are being blocked by PLINQ Query?

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, plinq

I am trying to find a Levenshtien match between two datasets. I try to find the edit distances of a ListA which contains thousands of values against another ListB which contains millions of records.

What I have achieved so far is I use a LINQ Projection to get a cross product of batches of values from sourceDataBatch(500 batchsize) and TargetDataBatch(500000 batchsize) and then run a parallel query to get the levenshtien product. I have a 8 core processor and the query works fine when I process a 1.5K List with 4.3 million records. But if I increase the List size to 2K it stops altogether. I suppose the threads get blocked after processing 1.5K records.

Please advise what/s happening in this scenario.

This is my code:

```
var pairs = (from wordToMatch in currentSourceDataBatch
             from similarWord in currentTargetDataBatch//cross product
             select new LevenshtienInput { WordToMatch = wordToMatch, SimilarWord = similarWord });

 var matches = pairs.
               AsParallel().                                    
               Where(pair => IsLevenshteinMatch(pair, threshold)).
               ToList();
```

Here is my Levenshtien Method:

```
 private static bool IsLevenshteinMatch(LevenshtienInput pair, double threshold)
 {
   int leven = Levenshtein.Distance(pair.WordToMatch, pair.SimilarWord);
   int length = Math.Max(pair.WordToMatch.Length, pair.SimilarWord.Length);
   double similarity = 1.0 - (double)leven / length;
   if (similarity >= threshold)
   {
     pair.Similarity = similarity;
     return true;
   }
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: is there any exception?

Comment: There is no exception as such. But the process just stops after finding the matches of 1500 records. I don't understand why. I am guessing it could be a thread abort excpetion but I cant catch it

Comment: I read this from a site I was browsing " .NET Framework 4, PLINQ has an internally hardwired limit on the number of data elements in an 
input data source that are supported:  2,147,483,648. This means that PLINQ should only be used for 
streaming scenarios where fewer than this number of elements will be processed. In most scenarios, this limit 
should not be problematic."

Comment: Also, given that you aren't using the `LevenshtienInput` class for anything, I would consider using a `ValueTuple` instead.

Comment: Assuming the PLINQ limit is true, perhaps you can batch the query into 2 million row chunks? See [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/plinq-and-int32-maxvalue/).